# Role of wavelength in the representations of the translation group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, quantum-mechanics

In the representation theory of the translation group we have $U^p(x)=e^{ipx}$ where $p=2\pi/\lambda$. I know in quantum mechanics this ends up being momentum somehow. And we can also see that $p$ is like an angular speed on the complex plane. Is this basically the intuition behind these infinite representations? Kind of like, okay all the representations reach $x$ but at different speeds? Is there some other way to think of this intuitively?

Comment: I don’t think the “angular speed” thing plays a role here.

Comment: That is the only thing differing the reps though, otherwise they are all the same. Are there real valued analogues of the complex irreps? To get a better idea through them?

Comment: I mean, I would think of them as “spatial frequencies”, instead. They parametrize the plane waves, they don’t actually describe circular motions. There is a lot of information in this blog post; https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/06/25/the-uncertainty-principle/

But don’t get lost there.

Comment: So the fact that a higher $p$ makes the each rep spin faster (with x) in the complex plane is not related to speed or momentum? Or is that spinning speed just a coincidence? I felt like this was the only thing differing the reps, otherwise why not just stick with a faithful rep.

Answer (score 0):

I think you malformed your operator. In the position representation, the translation operator is
$$
U^p(\Delta x) = e^{i \Delta x ~ \hat p/\hbar }= e^{\Delta x ~ \partial_x},
$$
which then amounts to Lagrange's shift operator,
$$
U^p(\Delta x)  f(x) = f(x+\Delta x).
$$
Here, $\Delta x$ is a constant number not acted upon by $\partial_x$.

(I wouldn't go there, but if you *really* wished to consider $U^p(  x) $ instead,
you see this is $ e^{x\partial_x}= e^{\partial/\partial(\log x)}$, so that
$$
U^p(x) f(x) = e^{\partial/\partial(\log x)} f(e^{\log x})= f(ex),
$$
a mere scale transformation.)

Comment: Okay. But the question is in more so in regard to why there are so many degenerate representations. If we take $p$ to correspond to the derivative operator then is the intuition behind the many representations have to do with the "speed" of the translation? Because in the complex plane a higher $p$ means a faster rotation for same $x$.

Comment: Up to a point. But you see the periodicity is fake. We are dealing with an infinite open line  *x* here. The point is the exponent is antihermitian in this picture, yielding unitary operators. You are right that the $\hbar$ setting the "speed" scale is arbitrary, and may be taken at your discretion.